# Wondering why the writer used the absolute positive term 'comeback' with the word 'disappointing' just to make it negative

Tags: word-meaning

Schumacher, who won a record 91 Grand Prix victories, left the sport last year after a disappointing three-year comeback with Mercedes following an earlier retirement from Ferrari at the end of 2006.

http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-04-04/michael-schumacher-showing-moments-of-consciousness/5369056
Three-year comeback. 
To the extent that my knowledge is involved, and according to Longman, **make a comeback** is always a positive stuff. Here in this context but it seems that it is a negative thing, doesn't it? 
Comeback meaning in Longman: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/comeback

Answer (score 4):

Welllll.... To "make a comeback" is a positive thing. (Well, assuming that what you're doing is positive. "The former serial killer decided to make a comeback with three more murders" ... not so positive.)

But a comeback is not necessarily successful. We often talk of someone "attempting a comeback", meaning he might come back and he might not. In this case, a "disappointing comeback" means that he tried to make a comeback but it didn't really work out very well.

Many terms that are generally positive could be mitigated in this sense. You might say someone had a "limited victory" or "achieved only modest success". We have the phrase "Pyrrhic victory", meaning something that seemed like a victory but where the cost was so high that it wasn't worth it.

Comment: So 'attempted comeback' would be more accurate.  But I suspect 'disappointing three-year attempted comeback' would just be too awkward.

Answer (score 1):

"To make/have a comeback"  is neither positive or negative , it simply describes a fact. And a comeback can be successful or not. You think only of the case of Schuhmacher,
but think of old pop singers that come back on stage after several years. I don't see something positive or negative in such a decision.